# Android Thread and ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, multithreading, google-app-engine, listview, runnable

I'm getting data as string from the Google App Engine so I have to do it in a thread. Next I want to display it in a ListView and I'm trying to do something like this code:

```
public void ShowContacts (){    
    new Thread(new Runnable() {         
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                final RestClient client = new RestClient("http://xxx.appspot.com/client");
                client.AddParam("userName", "user");
                client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
                _listView.post(new Runnable() {                 
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String s = client.getResponse();
                        String[] items = s.split(";");

                        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);                         
                        //_listView.setAdapter(adapter);                            
                    }
                });                             
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

This code is not working for me. Is there any way to get some value from the thread and set it to a global variable or construct an ArrayAdapter directly in the thread or something else?

Comment: `This code is not working for me.` What about it is not working? It will help if you are a bit more specific about the trouble you are facing.

Comment: When I'm trying to construct adapter I have this error: "The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new Runnable(){}, int, int, String[]) is undefined"

Comment: Inside of your Adapter constructor args change `this` to `NameOfYourActivity.this` but fill it win with the real name for your Activity class. Also I recommend taking a bit of time to brush up on Java before you delve too far into Android =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for getting data from server and add to ListView as:

```
public class getDatafromserver extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

          @Override

      protected void onPreExecute() {
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

         final RestClient client = new 
                             RestClient("http://xxx.appspot.com/client");
            client.AddParam("userName", "user");
            client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
          String s = client.getResponse();
          return s  ;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {                           
                    String[] items = result.split(";");

                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);                         
                    _listView.setAdapter(adapter);  
      }
}
```

start this AsyncTask from your Ui thread as:

```
new getDatafromserver().execute("");
```